# Is there a way how to intercept HTTP request in PhoneGap on Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

There is a quite common technique used in iOS on PhoneGap: Interception of HTTP (or URL) protocol in order to deliver content for PhoneGap-based app from alternative sources (e.g. from cache). You simply implements new protocol using [NSURLProtocol and co](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/).

So you can introduce e.g. `cache://server1/lookup1.json` type of URL (scheme is 'cache') that can be called from JavaScript inside PhoneGap and it will reach your NSURLProtocol implementation so that you can e.g. look into local cache prior asking a real server. I guess this is quite nice way how to implement apps that can operate even in offline mode (for limited time of course).

Now the question: Is there a similar possibility on Android?
I know that there is no direct version of NSURLProtocol (and even cannot be - you are typically in Java/Dalvik runtime and PhoneGap web browser component is running as native component). So I'm likely looking for more creative ways how to intercept that ... maybe in JavaScript, maybe in PhoneGap/Cordova Android code, maybe some native plugin to browser component.

I would be grateful for any hints here, I actually need to port PhoneGap-based application that is build this way on iOS to Android.

Answer (score 1):

@Ales you can easily intercept any scheme in any platform no matter its iOS or Android using a custom JavaScript function. The Phonegap webview does not open urls that starts with  javascript, rather it skips it for further processing to the javscript code itself.I have prepared a small working demo for this.Hope it meets your requirement.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(event) {
      var hrefValue = $(this).attr('href');
      var pattern = /^((cache|myapp):\/\/)/; // Add schemes to this list according to your need. i have added two
      if(pattern.test(hrefValue)) {         
        event.preventDefault();         
        var tempArray = hrefValue.split('://');
        var urlScheme = tempArray[0];
        var urlPath = tempArray[1];
        // perform specfic actions based on scheme
        if(urlScheme == 'cache') {      
             $.getJSON( 'http://'+urlPath, function( data ) {           
                $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
             });    
        }
    }
});
</script>
<style>
a { display:block; }
</style>
<a href="cache://ip.jsontest.com">Cache Scheme</a>
<a href="http://ip.jsontest.com">Http Scheme</a>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm actually aware about this possibility. However I want to intercept in non-intrusive way. In your example `href` attribute is JavaScript function call, I'd like to keep that as href="cache://ip.jsontest.com".

Comment: i have edited my answer to intercept the url scheme in non-intrusive way.pls let me know if it works

Comment: Looks like this is the best (and only) answer so far. I honestly hoped in something outside of the Javascript but it seems that it is the only way forward on Android.